# Can I use 'better still' in negative sentences?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english, negation

Can I use *'better still'* in a negative sentence? I'm especially interested in American English usage. Does it sound natural to say:

> You may not have the access to a trusted counselling, or better still,
>   to a 24/7 support?

Meaning that the latter would be much better, but it's difficult to get?

Comment: Sure. You are not reinforcing a negative there, but the *alternative* to a negative, which would make it a positive.

Comment: I would not. Also it is not working well as a question. 
_Do you not have the access to a trusted counselling, or better still, 24/7 support?_ If the question mark belonged to the "Does it sound naturally" then the sentence could be _You may not have the access to 24/7 support or even trusted counselling_

Comment: I disagree with Robusto - the original sentence really confuses me, and I'm a native speaker. It only makes sense to me if I substitute "better still" for something like "more importantly"

Comment: Do you consider 24/7 support to be the better option than trusted counselling?

Answer (score 14):

As an aside, I think three articles can be dropped to form a clearer sentence.
Also, the question mark confuses me a little bit, because the sentence is structured as a factual statement, not as a question. You can of course add a question mark to turn any sentence into a question, using intonation, but I'll assume a statement for now.

> You may not have access to trusted counselling, or better still, to 24/7 support.

The obvious problem is that it's not clear that access to 24/7 support is *also* affected by the negation, because of the semantic clash with *better*. I would suggest to use another option, to indicate that *24/7 support* is *even harder to find*, rather than *much better to have*:

> You may not have access to trusted counselling, *let alone* 24/7 support.

As [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/let%20alone) says for *let alone*:

> to say nothing of :  not to mention —used especially to emphasize the improbability of a contrasting example
>   “he would never walk again let alone play golf — Sports Illus.”
>   “how many ever see an Ambassador or Minister, let alone a President — Robert Lacville”

Comment: This is a dodge. There is nothing wrong with *better still* in the construction. In fact, the latter has attractive rhetorical consequences, given that it paints the the entire alternative as something to be desired.

Comment: The original sentence actually confused me. _No access to x_ versus _better still to y_ made me wonder why _no access to x_ was in any way a _good_ thing. I expect _better still_ to introduce something that is _even better_ than the preceding part, but in this case, the preceding part is not good at all, it is actually _negative_.

Comment: @robusto as a native speaker, the original sentence confused me, while the suggested *let alone* alternative makes perfect sense to me. that's hardly a "dodge". this is an excellent answer. language is defined by usage not what a textbook says.

Comment: Who said anything about a textbook? I'm going on how it sounds to me. YMMOV.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "negative" version you're looking for is *worse yet*:

> You may not have access to trusted counseling, *worse yet* 24/7 support?

Alternately *or worse*:

> You may not have access to trusted counseling, *or worse*: 24/7 support?

Or you could reverse the order to make use of *much less*:

> You  may not have access to 24/7 support, *much less* trusted counseling?

The order must be reversed in this last structure so that the scope of the former encompasses the latter.

Comment: This is not a question, so it shouldn't have a question mark, unless it's a case of repeating something just said in an unbelieving voice. But in that case it should have quotation marks as well.

Comment: Depends on the context. Regardless, I'm just re-using the asker's original example, take it up with them.

Comment: If an ungrammatical sentence goes in, generally an ungrammatical sentence comes out; especially when discussing rules of grammar and meaning.